# Visual Studio 2019 unable to edit in diff when file type is .jsx

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio

When comparing .jsx files with the unmodified version, the file is locked and I can't make changes. I tried with other file types (.cs, .js) and I can edit those while comparing.

- I am using git source control
- I am not running the project
- When I highlight the file it says {filename}.jsx;Head vs. {filename}.jsx

Does anyone know if there is a setting I can change for this?